# Sum json quantity with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is loop through json objects, find if there are objects with the same product_id and if there are it should sum the quantity of those objects.
Code:

```
$data = [];
$objects = $this->reports()->getBasicMeans($this->id)->get();
foreach($objects as $object)
{
    $data[] = $object->json;
}

$json['meanings'] = $data;
```

This is how I wrote my query:

```
public function scopegetBasicMeans($query, $market = null)
{
    $query->where('market_id', $market)->where('type', 1)
        ->join('product_assets', 'product_assets.report_id', '=', 'reports.id')->select(
            DB::raw('
                CONCAT("[", group_concat(substring(product_assets.resources, 2, length(product_assets.resources) - 2)), "]") AS json
            ')
        );
}
```

RESULT:

```
"meanings": [
    "[
    {\"name\": \"Product 1\", \"product_id\": \"1\", \"quantity\": 4},
    {\"name\": \"Product 1\", \"product_id\": \"1\", \"quantity\": 1},
    {\"name\": \"Product 1\", \"product_id\": \"1\", \"quantity\": 1},
    {\"name\": \"Product 1\", \"product_id\": \"1\", \"quantity\": 4},
    {\"name\": \"Product 2\", \"product_id\": \"2\", \"quantity\": 4},
    {\"name\": \"Product 3\", \"product_id\": \"3\", \"quantity\": 4},
    {\"na]"
]
```

So basically it should search for object with same the product_id and if there are multiple object with the same product_id it should sum the quantity of
all objects with the same product_id into one so the results should be like the following:

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
"meanings": [
    "[
    {\"name\": \"Product 1\", \"product_id\": \"1\", \"quantity\": 10},
    {\"name\": \"Product 2\", \"product_id\": \"2\", \"quantity\": 4},
    {\"name\": \"Product 3\", \"product_id\": \"3\", \"quantity\": 4},
    {\"na]"
]
```

Is this even possible and how could I achieve this, I just started working with mysql json and I have no idea. 
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write it for you**

Comment: All we need to see is the JSON you have created AND the code you have tried to write to process it into your required result. This currently looks more like a spec that a question.

Comment: I have given you the query I wrote which should do the following and the results i get.

Comment: provide us the code you have written to get the data.

Comment: Yes, so what you are asking is for one of us to write the code to produce the specified output. Thats not an On Topic question. That is a plain and simple **DIFM**

Comment: _Who upvotes questions like this?_ Please read the tooltip you get when you hover over the Upvote icon and re-evaluate your upvote

Comment: decode the json, loop it and match the data as per your condition, modify it and add it in new array, then encode new array and save it in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decode the json and then count quantity of products with same id and then encode it back.

```
$data = [];
$pId = [];
$objects = $this->reports()->getBasicMeans($this->id)->get();
foreach($objects as $object)
{
    $newData = json_decode($object);
    $data[$newData->product_id]['name'] = $newData->name;
    $data[$newData->product_id]['product_id'] = $newData->product_id;
    if (!in_array($newData->product_id, $pId)) {
        $pId[] = $newData->product_id;
        $data[$newData->product_id]['quantity'] = $newData->quantity;
    } else {
        $data[$newData->product_id]['quantity'] += $newData->quantity;
    }
}

$json['meanings'] = json_encode($data);
```

This might help you to achieve what you want.